# BC - no "\\n" at the end + start with zeros?

Tags: bash, bc

This is a `bc` output, e.g.:

Input:

```
echo "scale=10; BLA-BLA-HERE-NOT-IMPORTANT" | bc
```

Output:

```
.3708446283953709207058828124021300754352578903651372655882743141882\
77124645102027246581819139527644919407424570060822470537797066353573\
96635.8038454068 days
```

Two Questions:

- can the output be rounded to something like "0.3708..."?
- can I remove the "\n"-s from the end?

I can't find any max width option in `bc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this code:

```
echo "scale = 4;  3.5678/3" | bc | tr '\n' ' '
```

Setting `scale` for `bc` is supposed to do the rounding job. You can substitute the division part with your desired command. The output of `bc` is again piped to `tr`, which converts the newline (`\n`) to white space. For the above command I get the following output:

```
1.1892 user@localhost:~/codes$
```

Comment: This does not work as expected: try `echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc | tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 8):

With the GNU implementation of `bc`, there is an environment variable you can set called `BC_LINE_LENGTH` that will either disable the backslash + newline feature or will extend it. Newer versions allow you to disable it with a value of 0 like this:

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc <<<"2^4096"
```

Older versions don't have the "0 turn off" feature and require you to set the value to a large enough value so that it doesn't affect you:

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=10000 bc <<<"2^4096"
```

Seems like this would be a good environment variable to set in your shell if you use bc a lot and don't like the line wrapping. If you're using `bash`, just place this in your `.bashrc`:

```
export BC_LINE_LENGTH=0
```

Comment: Nice, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ OUT=$(bc <<< "2 ^ 256")
$ echo "$OUT"
11579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056403945758400791\
3129639936

$ OUT=${OUT//$'\\\n'/}
$ echo "$OUT"
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

Comment: Wow, that's a complicated way (and originally wrong, too) of writing `OUT=${OUT//$'\\\n'/}`.

Comment: @Gilles I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

So maybe answer just for myself, but combination of everything would be

```bash
BC_LINE_LENGTH=10000 bc -l <<< "scale=200;1/3" | tr "\n" " "
```

For example calculation of energy consumption

```bash
BC_LINE_LENGTH=10000 bc -l <<< "scale=2;`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now`/1000000"
```