# Convert to Single line output of bc command

Tags: command-line, text-formatting, bc

```
echo 'obase=2; 3402823669209384469321375 ' | bc
```

10110100001001001101110000110101000010010101110011010101100110001011\

01011010011111

I would like to convert the multiple line output into a single line with single command.Thanks

Tried with "tr" able to get rid of \ but output is in 2 different line

```
echo 'obase=2; 3402823669209384469321375 ' | bc  | tr '\' ' '
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90083/117549 May help

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I got it working by modifying as $export BC_LINE_LENGTH=0;echo 'obase=2; 3402823669209384469321375 ' | bc